# Python - IndentationError: expected an indented block (Unusual Indentation Error involving a class)

Tags: python, class

While trying to develop a class, I got this error.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import itertools as it
from scipy.integrate import quad
import astropy.cosmology
from astropy import units as u

class NFW:  

File "/Users/alexandres/Illustris/Scripts/NFWprofile2.py", line 10

               ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/alexandres/Illustris/Scripts/NFWprofile2.py"]
[dir: /Users/alexandres/Illustris/Scripts]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

How is this an indentation error?

regardless if i define the class as `NFW()` or `NFW(object)`, this is occurring.

This is being edited through Sublime 3

Comment: What comes after the line with the class statement?

Comment: It expects an indented block where the body of the class is, but it's nowhere to be found...

Answer (score 5):

If that is your entire file, you are missing the required body of the class. You can create an empty body using the `pass` statement:

```
class NFW:  
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred because you have a block with no statements in it.

ie, the `class NFW` is empty.

For creating a minimal class,

```
class MyEmptyClass:
        pass
```

In your case

```
class NFW:  
    pass
```

**The pass statement does nothing.** It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.